# bundler: not executable: rake

Tags: jruby, bundler, torquebox

I'm in the process of setting up JRuby 1.7 in a ubuntu vagrant box to work with torquebox. I'm using the [torquebox-remote-deployer](https://github.com/jkutner/torquebox-remote-deployer) gem to deploy the archive file and the app stuff to the virtual machine. Now, when the gem tries to execute `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
bundler: not executable: rake
```

Now, when i check in the vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/bin directory, rake and all the other needed executables are there. I've also tried running the bundle command through the local jruby install to ensure it is called properly, but I get the same result

```
/opt/jruby/bin/jruby -S bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Any suggestions? If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: So is the rake file that's there actually marked as executable? Not sure how you'd end up in that situation to begin with but the error message seems to be saying that 'rake' itself is there but just not marked executable (+x).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I checked the permissions and they were rwxrxrx but ill confirm later

Comment: Ah so it looks like it wasn't set to executable. It would seem each time I deploy the archive file, the permissions get re-set to read. Added in my deploy scripts to ensure it is executable properly.

Comment: By the way, feel free to post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Any how did you fix the permissions?

Comment: @fivetwentysix i used the chmod command recursively on the vendor/bundle/bin directory i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So is the rake file that's there actually marked as executable?

Not sure how you'd end up in that situation to begin with but the error message seems to be saying that 'rake' itself is there but just not marked executable (+x).

Answer (score 1):

If same question will be for rails script file solution will be:

Just update file permission to executable. It worked for me.

```
 chmod 777 -R script/filename.rb
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a "bug" with jar.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6194856

I ended up creating a separate ruby script for fixing permissions that I invoke with torquebox:remote:exec["bundle exec jruby path/to/script"].

Comment: Yeah i did that as well at somepoint. I ended up later switching things to install gems on the remote box, like it would be done when deploying an MRI app with capistrano. The transferring of vendor bundle in the knob:deploy was too heavy for my liking.